# XCGLogger: Ambiguous reference to member 'log'

Tags: swift, xcglogger

Trying to set up XCGLogger and receiving error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'log'

I see this issue was already [raised](https://github.com/DaveWoodCom/XCGLogger/issues/117) but I'm not clear on the solution..

Per the install guide added this global constant to AppDelegate.swift:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    let log = XCGLogger.defaultInstance()

    func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        log.setup(.Debug, showThreadName: true, showLogLevel: true, showFileNames: true, showLineNumbers: true, writeToFile: nil, fileLogLevel: .Debug)  
        return true
    }
```

Then in individual source files:

```
import XCGLogger
log.debug("A debug message")
```

What is the proper usage?

Comment: Where in AppDelegate did you put the code?  Is it in the AppDelegate class or global?

Comment: `nameOfYourProject.log.debug`? But probably renaming `log` to something else will be better. Were you able to find the colliding identifier `log`?

Comment: @ryantxr: Updated question

Comment: It seems `log` is also defined somewhere else in your project, possibly in some library. You could call `self.log` to refer to the `log` you have defined in `AppDelegate`.

Comment: @Sulthan - I don't think that's the issue...  same thing if I rename `log` to `logx`.   I'm guessing the AppDelegate global constants are not in scope.  Is there a recommend method to access them?

Comment: I have just tried to install `XCGLogger` using pods and I cannot reproduce the issue.

Comment: Ok I'm using pods as well...  Thanks for looking.   Will do some more research.  Realized I didn't update the Embedded Binaries config that the doc mentions.  Did you do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is rather simple. If you declare `log` inside `AppDelegate`, you are making an instance variable. To access it, you will have to access it as instance variable:

```
(UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).log.debug("test")
```

If you want `log` to be accessible everywhere, you will have to make it a global constant:

> In your AppDelegate, **declare a global constant** to the default XCGLogger instance.

```
let log = XCGLogger.defaultInstance()

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
```

(there is no need to declare it in `AppDelegate` file, you can basically put it anywhere in your code)

or make it `static`:

```
@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    static let log = XCGLogger()
```

and access it using:

```
AppDelegate.log.debug(...)
```

To explain the ambigious reference, there is a mathematical function called `log`, and there is also a `log` function in the `malloc.h` file. Since you are passing a `String` as the first parameter and neither of the two functions is a match, the compiler warns you that it does not know which of the two functions you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Also I guess it's better to create global constant file and create something like this (if you've declared log in `AppDelegate`):

```
let LOG = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).log
```

and then simple use `LOG.error("error")`